Who defines datacenter tier norms
Who defines Tier 1, Tier 2, and Tier 3 for data centers?
Are these documents available somewhere on the net?

I can understand that a question is downvoted, but it would be nice to know why. I don't really get why this one desserves that...

https://web.archive.org/web/20131230235600/http://www.te.com/content/dam/te/global/english/industries/enterprise-network-solutions/knowledge-center/documents/enterprise-white-paper-tia-942-data-center-standards-overview-102264ae.pdf

Hm - this looks like a good candidate for re-opening. It's not a subjective question, Zac67 gave a definitive answer (and that should be posted, with an excerpt, as the answer)

The question needs to provide examples of tiers that they are referring to. This is too broad as-is. Additionally, most of the question is filler, and the filler should be removed. Statements such as " I have tried to google for it but all the time I'm redirected" and "The title says it all" aren't constructive.
